# Listview lost state and info

Tags: android, mobile

I have an android application that fills a listview with information, and in this listview there is a validation that aligns the color of the line according to the priority of each record (for example, yellow = 1, green = 2, etc ...).

What happens and when it is a listview is initially loaded as a match correctly in each of the records, however, if you are a means of registration, regardless of whether you do multiple scrool's throughout the listview, this is the last time we lost these priorities and the records become all one color. The same happens if I put an application in the background and when I put it back in the foreground the records pass to appear all the same color.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please provide your code otherwise it will be difficult to track down your problem

Comment: Can you also provide an image or a video to visually describe the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setIconColorFromPriority(short prioridade, ImageView icon) {
    if (prioridade <= 0) {
        prioridade = 8;
    }
    switch (prioridade) {
        case 1:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_1)); //VERMELHO
            break;
        case 2:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_2)); //LARANJA ESCURO
            break;
        case 3:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_3)); //LARANJA
            break;
        case 4:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_4)); //AMARELO
            break;
        case 5:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_4)); //AMARELO
            break;
        case 6:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_4)); //AMARELO
            break;
        case 7:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_5)); //VERDE
            break;
        case 8:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.sem_prioridade)); //VERDE
            break;
        //codigo 9 para a prioridade é referente aos recursos AGENDA
        case 9:
            icon.setTag(getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.prioridade_Agenda)); //ROSA SHOCK
            break;
    }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:longClickable="true" />


        <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lista_vazia" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        layout="@layout/progress_loading_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code you requested ...

Basically if I scroll the list it starts to put the same color in all the icon, and should lie the respective colors in each of them ....